# C# WPF-How to show button is pressed on UI when key on keyboard is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing a calculator look-alike application. I wish to do like when I press key "1" on the keyboard, the "1" button on the calculator UI will be pressed as well, and then return to its original state. Here's my code for the buttons, when button "1" is pressed, number "1" will show in the text box.

```
private void KeyPadBtn_Press(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button keyPadBtn = e.Source as Button;

            switch (keyPadBtn.Name)
            {
                case "OneBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "1"; break; }
                case "TwoBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "2"; break; }
                case "ThreeBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "3"; break; }
                case "FourBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "4"; break; }
                case "FiveBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "5"; break; }
                case "SixBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "6"; break; }
                case "SevenBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "7"; break; }
                case "EightBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "8"; break; }
                case "NineBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "9"; break; }
                case "ZeroBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "0"; break; }
                case "StarBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "*"; break; }
                case "HashBtn": { NumDisplayBox.Text = NumDisplayBox.Text + "#"; break; }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using a normal button?, or has applied some style?

Comment: you can use ASCII Code for particular button than perform operation on next page.

Comment: What is the OS you use, and what .net framework for your project?

Comment: Can you add a desired pressed state image along with your question? Cauz buttons are different in different OS

Comment: Typically, you'd define a style for your UI object (e.g. button), with a trigger configured to modify the object's visual state based on the value of a property somewhere that represents the key state. If you want something more specific than that, you really should include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates the problem.

Comment: Hi @Sayka, I'm using normal button, when the button is clicked, it will goto the KeyPadBtn_Press function, .net framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the keydown event for "1" you could switch focus to the 1 button and then use Sendkeys to send an enter.