# How to show button is pressed in UI for combination keys

Tags: c#, wpf, button, keyboard

Actually this post is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726681/c-sharp-wpf-how-to-show-button-is-pressed-on-ui-when-key-on-keyboard-is-pressed) (posted by me as well). I've a phone keypad in my UI and now I'm able to show the button is pressed when its corresponding key is down.

```
private void NumDisplayBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Key) 
  {
    case Key.D0:
    case Key.NumPad0:
      ZeroBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D1:
    case Key.NumPad1:
      OneBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D2:
    case Key.NumPad2:
      TwoBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D3:
    case Key.NumPad3:
      ThreeBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D4:
    case Key.NumPad4:
      FourBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D5:
    case Key.NumPad5:
      FiveBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D6:
    case Key.NumPad6:
      SixBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D7:
    case Key.NumPad7:
      SevenBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D8:
    case Key.NumPad8:
      EightBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
    case Key.D9:
    case Key.NumPad9:
      NineBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
      break;
  }

  if (((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift))
  {
    if (e.Key == Key.D3)
    {
      ThreeBtn.Style = (Style)FindResource("NormalButtonStyle");
      HashBtn.Style = (Style)FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
    }
  }
}

private void NumDisplayBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
  switch (e.Key) 
  {
    case Key.D0:
    case Key.NumPad0:
      ZeroBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4"); break;
    case Key.D1:
    case Key.NumPad1:
      OneBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4"); break;

    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

The problem is when hash key (Shift + 3) or star key (Shift + 8) is down, the '3' button (for case hash key) also be pressed in UI. How can I show that only hash button is pressed on UI when Shift + 3 are down, but not hash button together with '3' button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
//Make the button to have "pressed" feel when the corresponding key is pressed

private void NumDisplayBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift))
    {
      if (e.Key == Key.D3)
        HashBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");

      if (e.Key == Key.D8)
        StarBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
    }

    switch (e.Key) 
    {
      case Key.D0:
      case Key.NumPad0:
        ZeroBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D1:
      case Key.NumPad1:
        OneBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D2:
      case Key.NumPad2:
        TwoBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D3:
      case Key.NumPad3:
        {
          if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            ThreeBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");

          else
            ThreeBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");

          break;
        }
      case Key.D4:
      case Key.NumPad4:
        FourBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D5:
      case Key.NumPad5:
        FiveBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D6:
      case Key.NumPad6:
        SixBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D7:
      case Key.NumPad7:
        SevenBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      case Key.D8:
      case Key.NumPad8:
        {
          if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            EightBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");

          else
            EightBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");

          break;
        }
      case Key.D9:
      case Key.NumPad9:
        NineBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("PressedButtonStyle");
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
}

//Return back to its original style

private void NumDisplayBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.Key) 
  {
    case Key.D0:
    case Key.NumPad0:
      ZeroBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D1:
    case Key.NumPad1:
      OneBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D2:
    case Key.NumPad2:
      TwoBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D3:
    case Key.NumPad3:
      ThreeBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      HashBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D4:
    case Key.NumPad4:
      FourBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D5:
    case Key.NumPad5:
      FiveBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D6:
    case Key.NumPad6:
      SixBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D7:
    case Key.NumPad7:
      SevenBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D8:
    case Key.NumPad8:
      EightBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      StarBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    case Key.D9:
    case Key.NumPad9:
      NineBtn.Style = (Style) FindResource("ButtonStyle4");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `KeyEventArgs.Modifiers` property, and only handle the key-down when no modifiers are set.

Alternatively, use the `TextInput` or `PreviewTextInput` event to get the composed text instead of the actual key. This may be preferable anyway, as it will respond to any method of entering the appropriate text input, rather than relying on a specific key (for example, you won't have to have cases for all the possible keys, such as the top-row numeric keys and the numeric pad keys, as you are now).

Comment: Hi @PeterDuniho, if I use 'TextInput' or 'PreviewTextInput', how can I capture every single individual character I enter? If I set 'if (textbox.Text == "#"', it has to be the whole string is "#", not a character.

Comment: @YWah: The `TextInput` event is roughly (very roughly) analogous to Winforms' `KeyPress` event. Typically, the string will in fact be a single character long. It's a string because some input methods can in fact generate multi-character inputs. But most do not. Yes, it means for example your expression will look like `e.Text == "#"` instead of e.g. `e.Key == Key.D3 && (e.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0`. But that doesn't seem like a problem to me.